# Interface without IP connection status

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, network-programming, ip

I'm on Win7 and Qt and I need to track local network interfaces. The problem is - some of them don't have IP layer but I want to know if they are connected or not. 
I've tried

> QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces() from Qt

and

> GetInterfaceInfo() from iphlpapi.h

But both work only for interfaces with IP assigned. Duh. 
I've also tried

> pcap library

But `pcap_if_t` has no fields to track connection status, only MAC and others. 
I feel stuck between two layers and don't know how to handle this. 
I suppose there is a way with `WMI query` but it seems to be an overkill.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected"? Do you mean physically present on your local machine? That sounds like something for device manager functions.

Comment: Look at the Win32 `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` function. They will give you detailed information and statuses of every installed network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that internal interface status can be checked with the Win32 `GetIfTable()` function. 
This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getiftable) helped me a lot.